# Understanding folds in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I was going through the elixir documentation and I came across this code:

```
List.foldl([1, 2, 3, 4], 0, fn(x, acc) -> x - acc end) # 2
```

I tried for awhile to understand what it is doing but for the life of me I don't understand why this returns 2? If someone can take the time to explain this to me I appreciate that.

I totally understand that the second arg is an accumulator. with that being set to 0 shouldn't this return 10?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The initial value of the accumulator is `0` and you're doing `x - acc` for each x in the list. This is evaluated as follows:

```
x - acc = new_acc
-----------------
1 - 0   = 1
2 - 1   = 1
3 - 1   = 2
4 - 2   = 2
```

You probably meant to do `acc - x` if you want to subtract each `x` from the initial accumulator:

```
iex(1)> List.foldl([1, 2, 3, 4], 0, fn(x, acc) -> acc - x end)
-10
```

---

This the code I used to print the steps:

```
iex(1)> List.foldl([1, 2, 3, 4], 0, fn(x, acc) -> IO.puts "#{x} - #{acc} = #{x - acc}"; x - acc end)
1 - 0 = 1
2 - 1 = 1
3 - 1 = 2
4 - 2 = 2
2
```

Comment: I don't understand one thing about this. Why is the accumulator equal 1 twice in your example?

Comment: @Bitwise which operation you do not understand in particular: `1 - 0 = 1` or `2 - 1 = 1`?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at the exact line you quoted:

```
List.foldl([1, 2, 3, 4], 0, fn(x, acc) -> x - acc end) # 2
```

During the fold, the return value from the function in the third parameter gets assigned to the accumulator on each iteration:

```
acc starts as 0
x = 1 => acc becomes x - acc => acc = 1 - 0 = 1
x = 2 => acc becomes x - acc => acc = 2 - 1 = 1
x = 3 ...                       acc = 3 - 1 = 2
x = 4 ...                       acc = 4 - 2 = 2
```